# strtok_r to extract string inside quotes

Tags: c, string, strtok

my string is:

```
He is a "funny" guy
```

How can I extract that using `strtok_r`?

```
strtok_r(str, "\"", &last_pointer);
```

Is this a correct way of doing it? will the statement above skip first `"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My documentation for `strtok_r` says

> `char *strtok_r(char *str, const char *delim, char **saveptr);`
>
> On  the  first call to `strtok_r()`, `str` should point to the string to be parsed, and the value of `saveptr` is ignored.  In subsequent calls,  `str` should  be  `NULL`,  and  `saveptr` should be unchanged since the previous call.

So you should call it first with

```
strtok_r(str, "\"", &last_pointer);
```

and afterwards with

```
strtok_r(NULL, "\"", &last_pointer);
```

Comment: Does that mean, I cannot change `saveptr` at all? I mean if I know I have a leading `"` and I want to skip it before next `strtok_r` call, I cannot do `saveptr++` ??

Comment: Yep. That's what it means. If you change `saveptr` and it works, that's plain (bad) luck. It may stop working when the client is watching, or, more probable, when you recompile with a different compiler or compiler options.

Comment: Thanks, will take care of it.

Answer (score 1):

this POSIX function will skip all leading '\"' not the first. call strtok_r a second time with NULL as first parameter and have fun.